# OpenElec XMBC image reduces SD card to 128 MB

Tags: image, raspberry-pi, sd-card

I'm preparing an SD card with OpenElec XMBC to use in a Raspberry Pi. To start with, I have formatted the SD Card using [this software](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/). Then I followed the steps on [this page](http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php?title=Installing_OpenELEC_on_Raspberry_Pi#tab=Windows) to load the image on the SD card. Before writing the image to the SD card, the size is around 4 GB (as it should be). After writing the image, the size of the SD card goes back to around 128 MB. If I format the card again, it returns to 4 GB. Re-writing the image puts it back at 128 MB again.

I'm still awaiting the delivery of my Raspberry Pi to test it, however I find it hard to imagine that this is normal behavior or that the Raspberry Pi would recognize the 4GB. Has anybody had this issue?

EDIT:
I'm using Windows 8.1

UPDATE:
Tried it in my Raspberry Pi and it is showing 1G. Still 3GB missing.

Comment: It's probably re-written the partition table and created partitions that your OS doesn't recognise. I'd be willing to bet that the only partition your OS recognises is the one that's 128mb - OpenELEC is Linux based, so for example one of the partitions will be Linux Swap

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ben. I'll test it in the Raspberry Pi as soon as it arrives and will update here.

Comment: Alright Ben, you were partly right. In the Raspberry Pi it is showing 1 Gb. Still 3 Gb missing unfortunately.

Comment: If you DD/bitwise copy (which is what I assume the util is doing) an image that's only 1 gig, it would only show the disk as being 1 gig. You can resize or create a new partition. http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-981965.html

Comment: Yap, that was it. Thanks Ben.

Comment: I've left an answer - mind marking it as accepted to close off the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably re-written the partition table and created partitions that your OS doesn't recognise. I'd be willing to bet that the only partition your OS recognises is the one that's 128mb - OpenELEC is Linux based, so for example one of the partitions will be Linux Swap

If you DD/bitwise copy (which is what I assume the util is doing) an image that's only 1 gig, it would only show the disk as being 1 gig. You can resize or create a new partition.